# How to do transparent textures on Emission node in Blender Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I want to apply a transparent texture to an emssion node in a way that the the emission node will emit just from the not transparent parts of the image texture.  How to achieve this effect ?

Here' s a Picture of it
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking without any examples.

Comment: Use the alpha as the factor for a mix shader of Transparent and Emision

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you going for something like this?

[image: Glow with transparency]

If so, then it's as simple as someonewithpc said, just an *Emission* shader mixed with a *Transparent* shader using the texture for the *Fac*.

Comment: hey, i am using this setup but I want to animate the map. Not simply control the total transparency of the texture but rather for example have a spherical alpha ring / wave effect on the texture. Would anybody know how to do that? Technically masking the texture that goes into the factor node for the mix?