# How to make an Emission material transparent?

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine, transparency, emission

I would like to be able to see the green cube through my yellow cube while retaining the intensity and bloom of the Emission material:

[image]

I've seen [other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191333/how-to-make-emission-object-transparent-in-eevee) [questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/how-to-do-transparent-textures-on-emission-node-in-blender-cycles) that ask the same thing but unless I'm misinterpreting they all boil down to using a `Mix Shader` that takes mixes the `Emission` node and a `Transparent BSDF` node, which as you can see from my screenshot I am already doing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: blend mode in the material settings?

Comment: It's currently set to `Opaque`

Comment: And no combination of `Blend Mode`s and `Shadow Mode`s changes the result (although some will produce small artifacts)

Comment: if opaque, Eevee won't render transparency

Comment: Well even with Blend Mode set to for example `Alpha Blend` it looks the same, and when I render the image it looks exactly like in the screenshot too

Comment: It seems to be more of an issue of intensity; when I lower the intensity to 0.001 it becomes transparent, otherwise the light it emits makes it opaque.

Comment: Technically you should probably be using an Add shader instead of a Mix - certainly that would be how it would work in Cycles - since the Emission is a separate property of the surface that isn't affected by its amount of transparency. You don't mention in the question or tags whether this is related to Cycles or Eevee but it's implied by the above comments that it's Eevee only. Please update your question to be specific and/or at least edit the question to include a suitable tag to indicate which. As mentioned, in Eevee Blend Mode is very relevant and not physically accurate.

Comment: Sorry, I've never heard of Cycles or Eevee before. I installed Blender 2.90, what's the default there? Using the Add shader I can't get any transparency at all

Comment: With mix shader, this is a color complement issue. The green is used for yellow. If the green cube was blue, you should see it by transparency (white as yellow + blue = r g b = white)

Comment: Neither a blue or a red cube are really visible through the material unless you're in very low alpha values (< 0.05 on the Fac slider)

Comment: high intensity (around 15) but fac at 0.5: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJZPh.jpg

Comment: Could you send me that blend file to figure out the difference?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5Q37s1BD/

Answer (score 2):

one option to have transparent could be Adding a Fresnel to your Materials.
But i'm not sure if that's the look that you need for your project.

[image]

If you need more bloom, you can play with the render settings too.